# Worksheet cell does not update after macro runs

Tags: excel, vba

To give some context I got this module below. This module is also in my worksheet. Before starting the macro it works fine it highlights whenever there is not "Testing" in column L.

The problem: When I start my macro it does everything without error, but doesn't update.

So an example when I start it after the macro runs and is completed when I change "testing" into "Atesting" then it doesn't mark the cell red.

EDIT: Or when everything runs and is completed whenever I see "Atesting" in column L. I have to click the cell to see the change of the background becoming red.

```
    Option Explicit
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const RolesList As String = "Testing"
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "L2"
    Const Delimiter As String = "||"
    
    Dim rng As Range
    With Range(FirstCellAddress)
        Set rng = Intersect(.Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1), Target)
    End With
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim Roles() As String: Roles = Split(RolesList, ",")
    
    Dim dRng As Range
    Dim aRng As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim Curr() As String
    Dim cMatch As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    Dim isFound As Boolean
    
    For Each aRng In rng.Areas
        For Each cel In aRng.Cells
            If Not IsError(cel) Then
                Curr = Split(cel.Value, Delimiter)
                For n = 0 To UBound(Curr)
                    cMatch = Application.Match(Curr(n), Roles, 0)
                    If IsError(cMatch) Then
                        isFound = True
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        ' Remove this block if you don't need case-sensitivity.
                        If StrComp(Curr(n), Roles(cMatch - 1), _
                                vbBinaryCompare) <> 0 Then
                            isFound = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Next n
                If isFound Then
                    isFound = False
                    If dRng Is Nothing Then
                        Set dRng = cel
                    Else
                        Set dRng = Union(dRng, cel)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next cel
    Next aRng
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    rng.Interior.Color = xlNone
    If Not dRng Is Nothing Then
        dRng.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

---

Maybe this helps, this is the whole code I'm using, are there any mistakes?

Before I start macro:
[image]

After I start macro:[image]
After starting the macro it should still be red because it isn't in the role list, but it isn't't.

```
Sub AllInOne()

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Range("F2:F" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).Copy Destination:=Range("J2")
Range("F2:F" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).Copy Destination:=Range("K2")

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Delete

For Each rng In Range("F2:F" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row): rng.Value = LCase(rng.Value): Next rng
For Each rng In Range("K2:K" & Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row): rng.Value = LCase(rng.Value): Next rng
For Each rng In Range("J2:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row): rng.Value = LCase(rng.Value): Next rng

Worksheets("sheet1").Columns("A:M").AutoFit
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").UsedRange.Font.Underline = False
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2:Z5000").Font.Bold = False
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Range("A2:Z5000").ClearFormats
Range("A1:Z5000").Font.Color = vbBlack

Worksheets("sheet1").Columns("A:M").AutoFit

Dim cell As Range

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C" & lastRow)
    S = vbNullString
    If cell.Value <> vbNullString Then
        v = Split(cell.Value, " ")
        For Each W In v
            S = S & Left$(W, 1) & "."
        Next W
        cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).Value = S
    End If
Next cell

Application.Range("B1").Value = "testing"
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B1").Font.Bold = True

    Dim LastRowIndex As Integer
    Dim RowIndex As Integer
    Dim UsedRng As Range
 
    Set UsedRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    LastRowIndex = UsedRng.Row - 1 + UsedRng.Rows.Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
    For RowIndex = LastRowIndex To 1 Step -1
        If Application.CountA(Rows(RowIndex)) = 0 Then
            Rows(RowIndex).Delete
        End If
    Next RowIndex
 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
        Dim n As Long
        
Columns("D").Replace What:="vander", _
                    Replacement:="van der", _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchFormat:=False, _
                    ReplaceFormat:=False
Columns("D").Replace What:="vanden", _
                    Replacement:="van den", _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchFormat:=False, _
                    ReplaceFormat:=False
Columns("B").Replace What:="..", _
                    Replacement:=".", _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchFormat:=False, _
                    ReplaceFormat:=False

'Beta code'
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If Not IsError(r.Value) Then
            v = r.Value
            If v <> vbNullString Then
                If Not r.HasFormula Then
                    r.Value = Trim(v)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r
'NIEUW NIEUW NIEUW NIEUW NIEUW NIEUW NIEUW NIEUW '

Range("G2:G5000,A2:A5000,H2:H5000").Clear

Worksheets("sheet1").Columns("A:M").AutoFit

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const RolesList As String = "Testing"
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "L2"
    Const Delimiter As String = "||"
    
    Dim rng As Range
    With Range(FirstCellAddress)
        Set rng = Intersect(.Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1), Target)
    End With
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim Roles() As String: Roles = Split(RolesList, ",")
    
    Dim dRng As Range
    Dim aRng As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim Curr() As String
    Dim cMatch As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    Dim isFound As Boolean
    
    For Each aRng In rng.Areas
        For Each cel In aRng.Cells
            If Not IsError(cel) Then
                Curr = Split(cel.Value, Delimiter)
                For n = 0 To UBound(Curr)
                    cMatch = Application.Match(Curr(n), Roles, 0)
                    If IsError(cMatch) Then
                        isFound = True
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        ' Remove this block if you don't need case-sensitivity.
                        If StrComp(Curr(n), Roles(cMatch - 1), _
                                vbBinaryCompare) <> 0 Then
                            isFound = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Next n
                If isFound Then
                    isFound = False
                    If dRng Is Nothing Then
                        Set dRng = cel
                    Else
                        Set dRng = Union(dRng, cel)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next cel
    Next aRng
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    rng.Interior.Color = xlNone
    If Not dRng Is Nothing Then
        dRng.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Close Excel completely. Open Excel create a new workbook. Add the code into `Sheet1`. Write `Testing` several times in column L. Change one of those to `ATesting` --› color changes to red. • Please provide a [mcve] to reproduce the issue, because this code works here.

Comment: I can't reproduce either. You do not need to run this macro manually. It will fire whenever you exit a cell you are editing on the sheet in question.

Comment: I checked and it seems to work in just an excel file with 1 sheet, but with multiple sheets, I get the above problem for some reason.

Comment: @UlquiorraSchiffer This works with multiple sheets too. But it only works in one sheet: The sheet this code is written in. So if this code is added to `Sheet1` then this will work only in `Sheet1` but not in `Sheet2`. • Also note that this macro cannot be started, it is an event than runs automatically on a cell change. So your description is very unclear if you speak about *"When I start my macro it does everything without error …"*.

Comment: The issue is that your `AllInOne` macro turns off events `Application.EnableEvents = False` and in case of an error it will stay turned off because `Application.EnableEvents = True` will not be called then. Make sure that `Application.EnableEvents = True` is called in any case of an error (see [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)). Further when events are turned off and your `AllInOne` macro changes a value in column L the `Worksheet_Change` event will not run (and not change the color) because events are turned off.

Comment: I will look into this!

Comment: @Pᴇʜ my friend you are a real genius, thanks it working now!!!