# Data validation doesn't update after running macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have an follow-up question about this: [Worksheet cell does not update after macro runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66060943/worksheet-cell-does-not-update-after-macro-runs)

The data validation is supose to mark the background in the cell red if it doesn't exist in the `RoleList`, this part works fine, when data gets entered before running the macro, but after running the macro if there still exist a fault in the grammer of the column were data validation should apply it doesn't mark the background red.

So if I have `Moderatori` in the `RoleList` before running the macro it marks the cell red, because in the `RoleList` it says it should be `Moderator` so thats ok, but if I put `Moderatori` in the cell and start the macro it doesn't apply the red background for the cell (should be false).

Data validation part:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const RolesList As String = "Moderator"
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
    Const Delimiter As String = "||"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
    
    Dim rng As Range
    With Range(FirstCellAddress)
        Set rng = Intersect(.Resize(.Worksheet.rows.Count - .Row + 1), Target)
    End With
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        cel.Value = removeTrail(cel.Value, Delimiter)
    Next cel
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    Dim Roles() As String: Roles = Split(RolesList, ",")
    
    Dim dRng As Range
    Dim aRng As Range
    Dim Curr() As String
    Dim cMatch As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    Dim isFound As Boolean
    
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        If Not IsError(cel) Then
            Curr = Split(cel.Value, Delimiter)
            For n = 0 To UBound(Curr)
                cMatch = Application.Match(Curr(n), Roles, 0)
                If IsError(cMatch) Then
                    isFound = True
                    Exit For
                Else
                    If StrComp(Curr(n), Roles(cMatch - 1), _
                            vbBinaryCompare) <> 0 Then
                        isFound = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next n
            If isFound Then
                isFound = False
                If dRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set dRng = cel
                Else
                    Set dRng = Union(dRng, cel)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next cel
    
    rng.Interior.Color = xlNone
    If Not dRng Is Nothing Then
        dRng.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
    Worksheets(1).Columns(12).Calculate
End Sub

Function removeTrail( _
    ByVal SearchString As String, _
    ByVal RemoveString As String, _
    Optional ByVal doTrim As Boolean = True) _
As String
    If doTrim Then
        removeTrail = Trim(SearchString)
    Else
        removeTrail = SearchString
    End If
    If Right(removeTrail, Len(RemoveString)) = RemoveString Then
        removeTrail = Left(removeTrail, Len(removeTrail) - Len(RemoveString))
    End If
End Function
```

Module 3:

```
Option Explicit
 
Sub RemoveFormats()
     'Remove all formatting except changes in font and font size
     
     'Turn off screen updates to improve performance
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells
         'Remove cell colors
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
         
         'Remove all cell borders
        .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
         
         'Remove all special font properties and formatting
        With .Font
            .FontStyle = "Regular"
            .Strikethrough = False
            .Superscript = False
            .Subscript = False
            .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With
    End With
     
     'Restore screen updates to display changes
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     
End Sub
```

Comment: "So if I have Moderatori in the RoleList before running the macro it marks the cell red, because in the RoleList it says it should be Moderator so thats ok, but if I put Moderatori in the cell and start the macro it doesn't apply the red background" - it's not clear exactly the steps required to reproduce the problem.  It seems to be working for me.

Comment: When you enter the wrong role and start the macro it still shows you the red background? Because it doesn't for me.

Comment: It seems I'm being stupid again I had a module running with .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone witch deleted the background. I fixed it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed this in Module 3: `.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone` it works now, this part was ofcourse removing the background color from the cells.

I changed this part to: `Range("A:K").Interior.ColorIndex = 0` (So it doesn't remove the background color of the data validation happening in column L)

```
Option Explicit
 
Sub RemoveFormats()
     'Remove all formatting except changes in font and font size
 
 'Turn off screen updates to improve performance
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells
     'Remove cell colors
    '.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Range("A:K").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
     
     'Remove all cell borders
    .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
     
     'Remove all special font properties and formatting
    With .Font
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
End With
 
 'Restore screen updates to display changes
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub